# How to define One to One relationship in ServiceBuilder

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1 
I have two tables namely Customers and Orders  for my Module as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(SID integer,
Last_Name varchar(30),
First_Name varchar(30),
PRIMARY KEY (SID));


CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(Order_ID integer,
Customer_SID integer UNIQUE,
Primary Key (Order_ID),
Foreign Key (Customer_SID) references CUSTOMER(SID));
```

Could anybody please tell me how can i provide a One to One relation in servicebuilder file

I am worried as i have seen this in JIRA

https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-11479

Is that true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true - ServiceBuilder doesn't support one-to-one relations.

You can use the workarround given in the jira issue or build the service first and then define the associations using hibernate afterwards (dirty hack - hard to maintain).